# Attack on Cipher with Highly Related RoundKeys

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, key-schedule, related-keys

Consider a variation of AES with modified Key-Schedule and following observation on the Key Schedule.

If there exists a relation d between two Master keys, the key schedule is so weak that all sub-keys generated from the master keys have a relation d

Then how this aspect of a cipher can be exploited in the following scenarios?

1. Distinguish Ciphertext from Random Text
2. Partial Key Recovery
3. Full Key Recovery

Any guideline or reference to papers explaining the basics of such attack is appreciated.

Comment: it looks like homework / excercise https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Try to explain what have you tried and achieved until now and what exaxtly is the problem

Comment: @gusto2 actually : https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/asking-homework-questions and  https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-to-answer-homework-questions (let's not involve S.O. here :p )

Comment: :) wel its not homework assignment, and i dont want the solution i would like to do it myself. But some basic guidelines, reference to the some basic papers(not much advance which breaks some diffiuclt cipher, rather papers which may try to show related key attack in scenario of some dummy cipher) will be helpful

Comment: any help or papers references